# Native script : Build fails on iOS when migrating from 6.5 to 7.0

Tags: ios, xcode, vue.js, npm, nativescript

**Environment**
Native script version: 7.0.1
Node version: 10.16.0
Xcode version: 11.3.1

**Description**
I was using Native script 6.5 earlier and everything worked fine, but since when I'm trying to migrate it to latest I'm facing `this error: ARCHS[@]: unbound variable Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`

**Here are the dependencies I'm using- my package.json file**

{
"name": "MyApp",
"version": "1.4.11",
"description": "My App",
"author": "xyzzy",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
"@nativescript/core": "7.0.0",
"@nativescript/firebase": "^11.0.0",
"@nativescript/webpack": "3.0.0",
"@nstudio/nativescript-checkbox": "^1.0.0",
"@nstudio/nativescript-pulltorefresh": "^1.0.1",
"@nstudio/nativescript-snackbar": "1.0.0",
"@vue/devtools": "^5.0.0-beta.3",
"axios": "^0.19.0",
"moment": "^2.24.0",
"nativescript-app-tour": "^2.0.1",
"nativescript-appversion": "^1.4.4",
"nativescript-audio": "^5.0.4",
"nativescript-barcodescanner": "^3.2.2",
"nativescript-bottom-navigation": "^2.0.5",
"nativescript-exit": "^1.0.1",
"nativescript-insomnia": "^1.2.3",
"nativescript-local-notifications": "^4.2.1",
"nativescript-localize": "^4.2.2",
"nativescript-orientation": "^2.2.4",
"nativescript-platform-css": "^1.6.9",
"nativescript-sentry": "^1.9.1",
"nativescript-theme-core": "^1.0.6",
"nativescript-toasty": "^2.0.1",
"nativescript-ui-chart": "^8.0.2",
"nativescript-ui-listview": "^9.0.3",
"nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^9.0.3",
"nativescript-vue": "^2.4.0",
"net": "^1.0.2",
"vuex": "^3.1.1"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.4.5",
"@babel/preset-env": "^7.4.5",
"@nativescript/android": "7.0.0",
"@nativescript/ios": "7.0.3",
"@nativescript/types": "7.0.0",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-traverse": "6.26.0",
"babel-types": "6.26.0",
"babylon": "6.18.0",
"lazy": "1.0.11",
"nativescript-vue-template-compiler": "^2.4.0",
"node-sass": "4.12.0",
"ts-patch": "^1.3.0",
"vue-loader": "^15.6.4"
},
"main": "main"
}

**Update**

As I've updated the xcode version to 12 and this error is no longer there, yet I get a new one

Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NativeScript encountered a fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Observable cannot be invoked without 'new' at SharedNotificationDelegateCommon(file:///app/vendor.js:104217:38)
at SharedNotificationDelegateImpl(file:///app/vendor.js:104268:24)
at ../node_modules/nativescript-shared-notification-delegate/shared-notification-delegate.js(file:///app/vendor.js:104483:16)
at **webpack_require**(file:///app/runtime.js:75:30)
at ../node_modules/nativescript-local-notifications/local-notifications.js(file:///app/vendor.js:102210:51)
at **webpack_require**(file:///app/runtime.js:75:30)```

//Thank you for the help.

Comment: Using Xcode 11 - You need to use NS 6.8.x CLI, https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-6-7-xcode-compatibility/

Comment: @Yong thanks, and now I've updated my xcode version and I'm receiving new error, I've updated in question

Comment: it seems that Plugin nativescript-shared-notification-delegate does not support ns 7. https://nativescript.org/blog/nativescript-7-compatible-plugins/